# Import chartfx to Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, import, activex, delphi-xe2, chartfx

A number of delphi applications that I work with use an activex chartfx control. I realize that the company softwarefx stopped supporting delphi a while ago but we are transitioning to 64 bit builds and this component is our main obstacle. We could convert all our charts to TeeCharts if necessary but this would be a lot of changes.

I have gotten the 32 bit chartfx component to install and compile in xe2 but am unsure of the next step. Support did provide me with 64 bit dlls.

So I guess I have 3 questions:

1. has anyone sucessfully moved chartfx to a 64 bit delphi environment or
2. could you direct me to instructions on creating a component that is 32 bit at design time but can be 32 bit or 64 bit for compile?
3. is there a better way to do this?

edit: uploaded chartfx62 client server delphi code to http://www.filefactory.com/file/ce61229/n/Cfx62ClientServer_TLB.pas

Comment: Switching to a supported component (like TeeChart) may save you a lot of headaches.  I know this does not answer your question - which is why this is just a comment.

Comment: Or better, in general make sure you have source for the components that you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the 64 bit ActiveX DLLs to go with your 64 bit runtime. Designtime Delphi is still always 32 bit.

If ChartFX doesn't supply 64 bit version you are stuck. Having looked on the website it seems that the vendor does not yet supply a 64 bit ChartFX ActiveX and is soliciting feedback as to how much demand there is for it.

I would recommend transitioning to [TeeChart](http://www.steema.com/) which is native Delphi code and has a very strong tradition on Delphi. You can be confident of future support for other platforms as and when they become available.

Comment: I know the site doesn't have much on it but their support team did send me a version of the dlls that are supposed to be 64 bit. I don't have experience building components and am not sure how to integrate them to the delphi component or if that is possible. I think you are right, in the long run we will be better off with TeeChart. The boss thinks ChartFX is a better looking chart with better built in user options. one button changes chart style to view data how user wants, etc.